# Flexbox justify-content space

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, flexbox

I'm using flex box to make a layout for my products list but when I try to set justify-content to be space-between it works well on 4 items scenario but for less items (2 or 3) the space between them grows so how I set the space between items to be the same regardless the number of items in the row?

```
.productsContainer {
  background-color: $color_1;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.product {
  flex-basis: 23%;
  border: 1px solid $color_2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKEtH.png)

Comment: Try to change it to justify-content: center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
justify-content: space-between;
```

will divide the remaining container space into equal width chunks between your elements, you can not set the spacing.

I would recommend trying the [grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) for this kind of card placement.

Something like this should do it:

```
.productsContainer {
  background-color: $color_1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
justify-content: center;
```

and add gap property:

```
gap: 10px;
```

and play with the gap.